# How to disable/restrict a line of code after it has been run? (Python)

Tags: python, list, function

I'm very new to coding and Python. I'm making a simple "choose your adventure" type game in Python. The whole object of the game is to enter all 4 rooms/doors and acquire all 4 digits of the secret code to enter a locked door, which leads to the treasure. This is what im using to add a digit to the code:

```
from random import choice

code = range(10)
my_code = []

def add_code():
    if len(my_code) < 4:
        code_digit = choice(code)
        my_code.append(code_digit)
```

So for every room, I have puzzles and challenges to conquer. If you complete the challenge, I have it run the add_code() function. What I want to avoid is having a user repeatedly go to the same door, complete the same challenge, and add a digit to the list, without even having to open any other door or complete any other challenge. Is there a way to make a certain line of code not run after it has already been ran once? Like, if door 1's challenge was completed and a digit was added to the code, is there a way to not let the user add another digit from door 1's add_code() function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Associate each challenge with a boolean flag. Set the flag to True when the player finishes the challenge, and check the flag before giving the player the option to do the challenge again.

For example, if you had a "punch monkeys" quest, you might have the following flag:

```
monkeys_punched_yet = False
```

When the player punches the monkeys, you'd set

```
monkeys_punched_yet = True
```

In the monkey-punching area, you'd have a check something like this:

```
if monkeys_punched_yet:
    description_text = ("You see a pile of bruised and battered monkeys "
                        "in a corner of the room.")
else:
    description_text = "You see a group of unsuspecting, punchable monkeys."
    options.append("punch monkeys")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But could you elaborate a bit? As I said, I'm very new to all this stuff...

Comment: @user2565883: Further elaboration added.

Comment: Thankyou! :D I wish I could upvote you, but my lack of rep says no. Btw, love the challenge. I just might use it haha.

Answer (score 0):

You could check to see if the new code is not already in the list of completed codes.

```
def add_code():
    if len(my_code) < 4:
        code_digit = choice(code)
        if ( code_digit in my_code):
           print("Already visited that room")
        else:
            my_code.append(code_digit)
```

Comment: But the number added to my_code is selected randomly from digits 0-9, so there would be no way to know if it was that certain room that added that certain digit. :(

Answer (score 0):

Use booleans:

```
door1 = False
door2 = False
door3 = False
door4 = False
```

After you have completed a challenge in one door, set the relevant door to `True`. Then, you'll want to have some kind of a centre to display each door. Think in a game how you're in the centre room, and you are surrounded by four doors. Your code would be something like this:

```
which_door = raw_input('Which door do you want to enter? ')
if which_door == "1":
    if door1: # This is short for "if door1 is True"
        print "You have already completed this challenge."
    else: # Otherwise, it is set to False. The challenge has not been started
        do_stuff()
        door1 = True
etc for each door...
```

---

By the way, there's a simpler way to make a random code:

```
>>> random.sample(range(10), 4)
[3, 4, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Yes, I have the center room with all kinds of choices i.e., (enter door 1, look around, try and escape) and this was just what I was looking for to solve this. Thanks!

Comment: I like that. A much neater way to add the code. Thanks again!

Comment: Why was this downvoted please? Even the OP has commented that it is a solution

Comment: Right? Thats not fair haha.

Comment: @Haidro: Upvoted, I see that there was nothing wrong with this post. Whoever downvoted, please state your reason.

Comment: You should use a dictionary or a list for the doors instead of a different variable for each door, otherwise this is a non-robust, un-maintainable code.

Comment: @InbarRose Although I agree with you, it's much nicer to read than a dictionary, especially for a person new to python. Also, isn't it faster than a dictionary?

Comment: No, because using a dictionary you would not need to have such nested code, and not as many conditional clauses... Just rework it yourself for a few minutes and see how much cleaner it can be.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is doing adding completed challenges to a list of completed challenges. Each challenge must have a unique identifier.

```
user.completed_challenges = set()
```

When opening a challenge, check if the challenge is in the list of completed challenge

```
if not challenge.uuid in user.completed_challenges:
   # do code

   # When everything is done add the uuid to challenges
   user.completed_challenges.add(challenge.uuid)
```

Also one thing you could do is to have for exemple two rooms that are the same challenge, if you do one of them. Both should be marked as "done". Then give both room the same unique identifier

It is quite simple but should do the job in your case I guess.

## explanations

Instead of using booleans, I'd rather use `uuids`. It can be strings or whatever. It has to be an identifier that is capable to identify single challenges.. For exemple `['room1', 'room2', 'room3', 'room4']`

The `set` prevent you from adding more than once elements. The problem with booleans is that it is not quite flexible to use. You'll have to create `n` variables for `n` challenges. It won't be very clean to add more challenge. When you have less than 5 challenges, it should work fine but if you want to add more, having a set that keep tracks of the challenges you've done is much better.

The other good thing about the set, is that you'll have a good idea which challenges the user already completed.

```
print "You completed challenges %s" % ', '.join(user.completed_challenges)
```

Whith booleans, you'll have to iterate over all hardcoded booleans which will get much much harder to handle with time.

Comment: I see how this would work. Thanks for answering! But personally, the whole boolean False/True thing makes more sense to me. Thanks again though!

Comment: With booleans it's not very flexible and will be harder to extend. I added an explanation btw.